# Google App Engine JPA 2.0 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, maven-3, datanucleus

[I have been scouring the internet for hours today](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo) and can't get this resolved.

I am trying to get my Google App Engine project configured to use JPA 2.0 with the latest as of this time Datanucleus packages. Everything compiles fine, but I keep getting a runtime exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil`

I am including the relevant parts of my `pom.xml` that refer to all the persistence stuff as well as my `persistence.xml` file.

Here is what I think are the relevant parts of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<gae.version>1.7.4</gae.version>
<datanucleus.version>3.1.1</datanucleus.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <api>JPA</api>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Here is my `persistence.xml` file contents: *[I updated the provider as per the instructions on the Google App Engine web site](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is the stack trace I am getting:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 56 more
```

**Can someone please point me in the right direction of what dependency I am missing?**

**What are the exact versions of the Datanucleus, Google and JPA dependencies that I need for the latest libraries?**

Answer (score 2):

You say you're using JPA 2.0, but you put **geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec v1.1.1** in your CLASSPATH, and that is JPA 1.0 API. As per the [GAE JPA plugin](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/orm/datanucleus-appengine/2.1.1/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.1.pom) POM, using **geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec v1.1** would make more sense, since it is the JPA 2.0 API. GAE JPA plugin and DataNucleus compatibility is defined in http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: If it can't find that class then you have a JPA 1.0 jar in your classpath that is hiding the JPA 2.0 jar classes, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google AppEngine DataNucleus plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.orm/datanucleus-appengine):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```